# Bash: run script in background and write output to log

Tags: bash, logging, background-process

I want to run script in background and write it output to log:

Here is my original script:

```
for i in `seq 1 3`; do ./script.sh $i &> "my_logs/"$i".log"; done
```

What I have tried:

```
for i in `seq 1 3`; do ./script.sh $i &> "my_logs/"$i".log" &; done
```

What is a proper way to do this?

```
for i in `seq 1 3`; do ./script.sh $i & &> "my_logs/"$i".log"; done
```

Comment: What is wrong with your attempt? (Aside from the unnecessary leaving-out of `$i` from the quotes: `"my_logs/$i.log"` is fine.)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want:

```
for i in `seq 1 3`; do ./script.sh $i > "my_logs/$i.log"; done &
```

Comment: I need each `./script.sh` to be runned as separate background process and this seems just run for loop in background?